# wxPython drag and drop matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I have a number of wx.panels, each containing a matplotlib figure (a thumbnail gallery). I want the user to be able to drag and drop any of these figures to another, bigger panel.

What I tried was binding to the wx.EVT_MOTION of each thumbnail panel. Unfortunately, it seems that the event is consumed by the figure as it never fires.

I then tried connecting to the 'motion_notify_event' of each figure but this one only fires when the mouse is over this particular figure.

Is it possible to somehow disable matplotlib events, so that the event gets to the panel underneath? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at the documentation and demos for [wx.DropTarget](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_drop_target.html) and [wx.DropSource](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_drop_source.html) and the [overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_dnd.html).

Code examples see: samples/dnd subdirectory of your wxWidgets installation or http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/dnd

You could also consider adding a tick box or button to each thumbnail that makes that one the large view.